# How do I get the URL of the new popup window in the CreateWindow event in GeckoFX 60.0.22?

Tags: vb.net, geckofx, windowsformshost

I am updating an application of GeckoFX version `45.0.34` to version `60.0.22`.
In version `60.0.22`, in the `CreateWindow` event of GeckoWebBrowser, the Uri property of the `GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs` object does not exist.

How do I get the URL of the new window in the `CreateWindow` event in GeckoFX `60.0.22`?

The following code works in version `45.0.34` but fails in version `60.0.22`:

```
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_CreateWindow(sender As Object, e As Gecko.GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.CreateWindow
    e.Cancel = True
    Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.ToString))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Omar!

I'm not super experienced in VB.NET but I know some C# and this is what worked for me in C#:

```cs
private void SelectedBrowser_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.WebBrowser.Url.ToString()));
        }
```

I'm not exactly sure how you'd do this in VB.NET, but if possible, try this:

```vb
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_CreateWindow(sender As Object, e As Gecko.GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.CreateWindow
    e.Cancel = True
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.WebBrowser.Url.ToString))
End Sub
```